# I cannot use any installation command because of GLIBC_2.28 error

Tags: apt, 18.04

while running sudo apt-get install packagename i got this error.
apt-get: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0)

```
The output of " cat /etc/apt/sources.list" is:
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

while running `dpkg -l libapt*`

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  libapt-inst    <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  libapt-inst1.4 0.8.16~exp12 i386         deb package format runtime librar
rc  libapt-inst1.5 1.0.1ubuntu2 i386         deb package format runtime librar
ii  libapt-inst2.0 1.6.6        i386         deb package format runtime librar
un  libapt-pkg     <none>       <none>       (no description available)
ii  libapt-pkg-per 0.1.33build1 i386         Perl interface to libapt-pkg
ii  libapt-pkg4.12 1.0.1ubuntu2 i386         package management runtime librar
ii  libapt-pkg5.0: 1.7.0ubuntu0 i386         package management runtime librar
```

cat /etc/lsb-release
`DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"`

Comment: You have 16.04 repository in your `sources.list`.

Comment: I'm very confused by what I'm seeing here:  Your repositories are from Xenial (16.04), your kernel may be from Xenial-HWE or Bionic, you have loaded packages from Bionic(18.04) (according to a comment on the answer) and you're system is looking for packages from Cosmic (18.10)

Comment: @Pilot6 Any thoughts on how someone could get into this situation?

Comment: The problem started when i was dealing with docker installation for 18.04.i was pasting the command **sudo apt install apt-transport-https**.

Comment: @CharlesGreen There are so many ways to shoot in your foot. I am not quite sure that OP has 18.04. What does `cat /etc/lsb-release` show?

Answer (score 0):

You have 16.04 repository set in your `sources.list` file.

I suggest to remove that file by

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then run

```
software-properties-gtk
```

and check there repositories like `main`, `universe`, etc.

That should create a new `sources.list` file with `bionic` reposiories instead of `xenial`.

Another way is to run `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

and paste there this text

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted universe multiverse  
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Then save it by Ctrl+O and exit by Ctrl+X.

Run `sudo apt update`.

Comment: I fear this may run deeper than that - the version of libapt_pkg5.0 that is running, is from cosmic

Comment: deleted the sources.list file.but for the second command i got the same error.

Comment: Yeah, but we can at least start from here. Then we can see.

Comment: ubuntu:~$ software-properties-gtk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/command-not-found", line 28, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound import CommandNotFound
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/CommandNotFound.py", line 19, in <module>
    from CommandNotFound.db.db import SqliteDatabase
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/CommandNotFound/db/db.py", line 5, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.5.0)

Comment: See the update. There is another way of fixing it.

Comment: no changes when following above commands.Same error shows after editing sources.list

Comment: I have no idea how you got there. You broke lots of things in your system.

Comment: reinstalling OS is only way?

Comment: It's obviously the easiest way. For the future don't run commands found in the net when you are not sure what they are supposed to do.

Comment: Yea.I realised the same.Thanks a lot for your support.