# /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by ./domoticz)

Tags: glibc

For my homeautomation I need GLIBC_2.28 or higher.
My os is:

```
pi@odroidn2:~$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.4 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
pi@odroidn2:~$ ^C
```

I also tried [this option](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1120412/i-cannot-use-any-installation-command-because-of-glibc-2-28-error)

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 has glibc-2.28 . Ubuntu package = `libc6`. ... Please note: Glibc *is* your OS (together with the kernel) and cannot be changed. Suggest : Install a later version. (Ubuntu 20.04 will be issued soon.)

Comment: Dear knud Thanks,  Is there a simple way to update to a lts version? Or is the 19 version also ok?

Comment: Upgrade is not simple. ( I never do upgrades, always new installs.) ... You can upgrade to 19.04 .... glibc = 2.29  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libc6&searchon=names . .... **Upgrade** : https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=all&gws_rd=ssl#hl=en&q=upgrade+ubuntu+18.04+to+19.04

Comment: update to tls 20... works great  Thanks for the support.!!!

Comment: Only now a other problem.. my disk is 100%... auto remove and purge are not working

Comment: Disk "100%" full : You should be able to delete e.g. some downloads and manually installed apps. After that you could do : `sudo apt clean` etc.  https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/5-ways-free-up-space-on-ubuntu